# Calculating Depreciation using php

Tags: php, html, loops, if-statement

this is my first time asking on here as a beginner at coding so forgive me if my questions seem like basic knowledge I'm still learning :)
so I was trying to recreate this form and output using html and php:
[this is the screenshot of the code I was trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dneNK.png)

and I managed to successfully produce the html and php (I'll add them for reference) however there is something in the calculation that is not exactly correct
my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Car Depreciation</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="depreciation.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Original Price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="price" size="5"> Dollars</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Residual Value</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="residual" size="5"> Dollars</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my php code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Value at<br>beginning</th>
                <th>Annual<br>Depreciation</th>
                <th>Accumulated<br>Depreciation</th>
                <th>Value at<br>end</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            //Declaration of variables
            $price = $_GET["price"];
            $residual = $_GET["residual"];
            $accumulateddep = 0;
            //Calculations, Loops and Printing
            for ($year = 1; $year <= 5; $year++) {
                $annualdep = ($price - $residual) / 5;
                $accumulateddep+=$annualdep;
                $begvalue=$price-$accumulateddep;
                $endvalue = $begvalue - $annualdep;
                if ($year % 2 == 0)
                    echo "<tr>
                    <td>$year</td>
                    <td>$begvalue</td>
                    <td>$annualdep</td>
                    <td>$accumulateddep</td>
                    <td>$endvalue</td>
                    </tr>";
                else
                    echo "<tr style='background-color:lightgrey'>
                    <td>$year</td>
                    <td>$begvalue</td>
                    <td>$annualdep</td>
                    <td>$accumulateddep</td>
                    <td>$endvalue</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

my issue is that when I test it out, I want the first year's calculation to use the entered value and then move on from there however what my code did was calculate depreciation for the first year then used that end value to continue (will insert a screenshot of my output for reference)
[screenshot of my output using my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcYBX.png)
what needs to be modified in order to accurately fix the depreciation calculation for the first year?
(quick update: someone mentioned I should state my example values in text so here they are: I use 17000 for the original price and 0.04 as the depreciation rate so the first year's calculation should be: 17000-3000=14000; 3000 is the annual depreciation according to the formula used to calculate it; the second year should use the end value of the first year so 14000-3000=11000 and so on for the five years)
thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please give us examples of the input values and the expected output values, and the current output values you're getting **as text** then we can test and re-use them. Thanks.

Comment: You need to identify the first iteration (which shouldn't be hard, since that's just year 1) and then set `$begvalue=$price` if it's the first one, otherwise do `$begvalue=$price-$accumulateddep;`. Just one simple `if` condition (or ternary expression).

Comment: the depreciation is just (initial value - final value)/years. This is the yearly depreciation. (14.000 - 2.000)/5=12.000/5 that is not 3000 like you show in your picture

Comment: @El_Vanja could you please clarify further?

Comment: also `$annualdep = ($price - $residual) / 5;` should be out of the for loop. You have to calculate once and then it is the same for each year

Comment: `if (first year) { beginning value is equal to price } else { beginning value is equal to price minus accumulated depreciation }`... You are immediately applying the calculation to your starting value for the first year, which is not what you want. You want the starting value to be equal to whatever you supplied through the input for the first year.

Comment: @LelioFaieta the annual depreciation formula should calculate (17000-2000)/5 which is 3000 this is a fixed depreciation formula so 3000 is the correct value

Comment: @El_Vanja thank you so much, that fixed it! have a lovely day/evening wherever part of the world you are :)

Comment: in your second example the table starts at 14000 that is not correct

Comment: Your code doesn't start from the full value but on the first depreciationed value. Also at the end of each year you have to reassign the final value of that year as start value of the next one

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You need to fix it for the rows color but should wortk as intended

```
//Declaration of variables
$price = $_GET["price"];
$residual = $_GET["residual"];
$accumulateddep = 0;
$annualdep = ($price - $residual) / 5;
$accumulateddep=$annualdep;
$endvalue=$price-$annualdep;
//Calculations, Loops and Printing
for ($year = 1; $year <= 5; $year++) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>$year</td>
    <td>$price</td>
    <td>$annualdep</td>
    <td>$accumulateddep</td>
    <td>$endvalue</td>
    </tr>";
    $price=$endvalue;
    $accumulateddep+=$annualdep;
    $endvalue=$price-$annualdep;
}
```